# mysqli_conn->query... is not giving any results when put inside for loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am unable to get result from the "$mysqli_conn->query" statement which is included in a for loop as shown in the code. The reason I am using for-loop is simple and can be judged from the code itself.

```
$name=$_SESSION["names"];
$size=sizeof($name);
for($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) { 
    //echo $name[$i]; //for testing
    $bname = $name[$i];
    $results = $mysqli_conn->query("SELECT product_name, product_code FROM products_list WHERE product_name='$bname'");
       if ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo $row["product_name"]."<br>";
        }
        else echo "I am Going Wrong way !!</br>";
}
```

The output I am getting is : "I am Going Wrong way !!" 
I also checked the contents of $_SESSION["names"]. Everything seems to be correct except the results.

Comment: Change `$row=$results->fetch_assoc()` as this will return false which is triggering your `else` statement. Instead try counting the number of returned rows and check that there is more than 0 returned rows.

Answer (score 0):

You're simply assuming your query can never fail, which is a very bad thing. You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). you are also simply assuming that your queries will ALWAYS return a result. if there's no rows available, `fetch` will return false, which you then treat as "wrong way".

At bare minimum, you should have a structure like this:

```
for(...) {
    $results = $mysqli_conn->query($sql);
    if (!$results) {
       die($mysqli_conn->error());
    }
    if ($results->num_rows != 0) {
          $row = $results->fetch_assoc();
    } else {
         echo 'no results';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But As you said, my query will always return a result. ($_SESSION["names"] is never empty in my case). I just tried using the same structure, but still the problem persists.